# Longitude and Latitude showing 0.0

Tags: java, android, gps, location

When I click the button it only shows the latitude and longitude of 0.0. Any ideas as to why? I simply followed an online tutorial.

If there is a better way to get the current location of a user please let me know and I will be sure to look into it. P.S. I do not have very much knowledge in Java and Android.

Thanks everyone. The issue was actually the fact that i did not have the permissions in the correct area. Thanks for all your help!

```
package com.example.android.getgpslocation;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    Button btnShowLocation;
    GPSTracker gps;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnShowLocation= (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_Location);
        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
                if(gps.canGetLocation()){
                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                    final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
                    mTextView.setText("Latitude "+latitude+" Longitude "+longitude);

                }else{
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

GPSTracker.java

```
package com.example.android.getgpslocation;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothClass;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;

import java.security.Provider;

/**
 * Created by alex on 7/1/2015.
 */
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener{

    private final Context context;
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    boolean canGetLocation = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    Location location;


    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1;

    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    public GPSTracker(Context context){
        this.context=context;
        getLocation();
    }
    public Location getLocation(){
        try{
            locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if(!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled){

            }else{
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if(isNetworkEnabled){
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_BW_UPDATES, this);
                }
                if(locationManager != null){
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if(location !=null){
                        latitude=location.getLatitude();
                        longitude=location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            if (isGPSEnabled){
                if (location == null){
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_DISTANCE_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    if (locationManager != null){
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if(location!=null){
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude=location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return location;
    }


    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location !=null){
            latitude=location.getLatitude();
        }
        return latitude;
    }
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location !=null){
            longitude=location.getLongitude();

        }return longitude;
    }
    public boolean canGetLocation(){
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is Settings");
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled, Please enable");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.getgpslocation" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

LocationManager is now the outdated API. Use the newer FusedLocationProviderAPI

Answer (score 0):

must use this 3 permissions to get the GeoLocation:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

to get the correct values of Lat/Log use the `onLocationChanged()` method:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
   longitude = location.getLongitude();
   latitude = location.getLatitude();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get location in onLocationChanged():

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
  longitude = location.getLongitude();
  latitude = location.getLatitude();
}
```

In location param you'll get Lang and Long Coordinates.

That's because basically the LocationManager is an async service and it takes time to get the position, however it is notified in onLocationChanged() event.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a lot of code if all you want to do is get the position. The code displayed under Works perfectly for me.
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements android.location.LocationListener {

```
private LocationManager locationManager;
double Latitude;
double Longitude;
double lati;
double longi;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 10,
            (LocationListener)this);

    Button posisjon = (Button)findViewById(R.id.posisjon);
    posisjon.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    lati = Latitude;
                    longi = Longitude;
                    TextView breddegrad = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.breddegrad);
                    breddegrad.setText(" " + lati);
                    TextView lengdegrad = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lengdegrad);
                    lengdegrad.setText(" " + longi);
                }
            }
    );                 
                }
            }
    );
}
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Latitude = location.getLatitude();
    Longitude = location.getLongitude();
}
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Gps turned off ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Gps turned on ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}
}
```